# Corona SDK - Touch event on Line not working

Tags: lua, event-handling, touch, coronasdk

I am trying to call touch Listener on line, but it is not working. If I try it on any other display object, it does work.

Simple Example:

```
local function touchListener(e)
    print("removeLine")
    print("Name: " .. e.target.name)
end
```

Above is touch listener function.

```
local line = display.newLine(sceneGroup, 0, 0, 100, 100)         
line:setStrokeColor(1, 0, 0, 1)
line.strokeWidth = 10
line.name = 'line'          
line:addEventListener( "touch", touchListener )
```

Added listener on `line`, but never works.

```
local circle = display.newCircle(sceneGroup, 150, 150, 50)            
circle:setFillColor(0, 1, 0, 1)
circle.name = "circle"
circle:addEventListener( "touch", touchListener )
```

Added listener on `circle`, and works perfectly.

Can anyone please suggest, what I am doing wrong with `line`?

Comment: Currently display.newLine() objects do not support touch/tap events. https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newLine.html

Comment: @kumar Thank you for your comment.  Any possible solution to this problem?

Comment: I feel , you can create a rectangle instead of line ? Tell me why do you need a line ?

Answer (score 1):

A single line is a small target to try and touch. Apple suggests that 44 points is the smallest touch target.